# Unable to ExecuteTransactionAsync Android Realm

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to do an asynchronous write with Realm and I need to pass the value to be persisted to the `executeTransaction` method like this:

```
public void updateAsync(final long id, final String title, final String content, final int color) {

    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Note note = getNoteById(id);
            if (note != null){
                note.setTitle(title);
                note.setContent(content);
                note.setColor(color);                    
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(note);
            }

        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Note Updated");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    });


}
```

The above code block failed with the error: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

SO my question is, how can I pass parameters to the background thread in Realm?

Answer (score 1):

When calling `executeTransactionAsync`, the `execute` block will run in a background thread, any Realm objects access from that thread need to be created/queried on that thread from the Realm instance which is the param of `execute`.

You can use the param `realm` to do queries. Just modify your `getNoteById(id)` to take the Realm instance as a param like `getNoteById(Realm realm, int id)`, and use the `realm` to do query.

Comment: Is there any need to close realm instance in onSuccess and onError??

Comment: Depends on your use case. The Realm passed in the transaction block callback doesn't have to be closed since it is not created by you. Realm will take care or it. But the instance created by you before calling the `executeTransactionAsync` needs to be closed. It is not necessary to close it in the `onSuccess`/`onError`, you can actually create it immediately after calling `executeTransactionAsync`. Or just follow the normal pattern, use activity's `onCreate`/`onDestroy` to do `getInstance`/`close`.